# How to add elements of an array to a numpy array to represent coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hey people of Stackoverflow,
I want to achieve the following procedure.
I have these 2 arrays:

```
a = np.array([175, 370])
b = [array([175, 176, 176, 176]), array([371, 369, 370, 371])]
```

the elements of b array should represent coordinates of some points

```
b = [array[x1, x2, x3, x4], array[y1, y2, y3, y4]]
```

and I want to add the elements of 'b' array to the 'a' array. so that I have the new 'a' array like this:

```
a = [[175, 370], [175, 371], [176, 369], [176, 370], [176, 371]]
so the 'a' array has the following meaning 
a = [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]
```

Which numpy function I shall use to achieve this ?

Comment: a and b arrays are defined like this
a = np.array([175, 370])b = [array([175, 176, 176, 176]), array([371, 369, 370, 371])]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) function to pair two arrays in `b` and append it to `a`

```
import numpy as np

a = [175, 370]
b = [np.array([175, 176, 176, 176]), np.array([371, 369, 370, 371])]

a = [a] # a will be changed from list of number to list of paired numbers
a += [list(c) for c in zip(b[0], b[1])]
```

Comment: thanks for ypur response (y)